# What does this Swift syntax mean?

Tags: swift

Can someone pleas help me with this syntax?
This is the protocol implementation:

```
extension ViewController: CustomCellDelegate {
    func cellStateToggled(cell: CustomCell) {
        guard let cellIndex = self.tableView.indexPath(for: cell) else { return }
        activeIndex = activeIndex == cellIndex ? nil : cellIndex
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

What I need help understanding is this particular line:

```
activeIndex = activeIndex == cellIndex ? nil : cellIndex
```

I understand the second part, ternary conditional operator but Im not sure what does the first part do:

```
activeIndex = activeIndex
```

And how does it all fit together?

Thanks!

Comment: See discussion of ternary operators in [_The Swift Programming Language: Basic Operators_](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/BasicOperators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH6-ID60).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To better understand

```
activeIndex = ( activeIndex == cellIndex ) ? nil : cellIndex
```

this means if the `cellIndex`  is equal to `activeIndex` then assign nil to `activeIndex` otherwise assign `cellIndex` , it's a shorthand to

```
if activeIndex  == cellIndex {
  activeIndex = nil
}
else
{
  activeIndex = cellIndex 
}
```